# Entity Framework SQL query on DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get 5 popular stories using Entity Framework query in a time span for example in 7 days or 14 days. I am storing views in a separate table with `DateTime` parameters with `StoryID`.

`Stories` table:

```
StoryID   Story
--------------------
1         story one
2         story two 
3         story three
4         story four
5         story five
6         story six
```

`Views` table:

```
ViewID     ViewDate             StoryID
---------------------------------------
  1        2015 07 17 19:00:00        1
  2        2015 07 17 20:00:00        1
  3        2015 07 17 21:00:00        2
  4        2015 07 18 19:00:00        2
  5        2015 07 19 19:00:00        2
  6        2015 07 21 19:00:00        1
  7        2015 07 23 19:00:00        2
```

**Edit:** (so far this is what how I think I should do it)

```
return _viewdb.ObjectSet.Where(p => v.ViewDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)).Select(p => new ExampleViewModel
            {
                StoryTitle = p.Sotries.Story,
            }).Take(5);
```

but this solution will get five story views from last 14 days, I want to return 5 StoryIDs of most viewed stories.

Please help

Comment: You should probably provide us with your models and some business logic you are working on before we can really assist you.

Comment: How about `views.Where(v => v.ViewDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14) && v.ViewDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));`

Comment: @JDupont: I just updated my question, Please check again. Thanks

Comment: @MatiCicero: How to get 5 most viewed StoryIDs in last 14 days?

Answer (score 1):

You should use GroupBy in your query

```
List<string> returnValue = entity.Populars.Join ( entity.Stories, p => p.StoryID, s => s.StoryID, ( p, s ) => new { p = p, s = s } )
                                          .Where ( a => a.p.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays ( -14 ) )
                                          .GroupBy ( b => b.s.StoryTitle, b => b.p.Date, ( i, h ) => new { StoryTitle = i, hits = h.Count ( ) } )
                                          .OrderByDescending ( c => c.hits ).Take ( 5 ).Select ( d => d.StoryTitle ).ToList ( )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.but how to get some value from Stories Table using foreign key from View Table in GroupBy so that I can get story title and pass it to the viewmodel.